# why pandas raise "KeyError: True" while "df.Apples==30 & True" is not a key too?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Based on official pandas documentations and help on:

```
pandas.DataFrame.loc
```

the loc allows to access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a Boolean array.
(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

but it look a Boolean array does not work really!

```
import pandas as pd

data=[[30, 21],[0, 121],[4, 121]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Apples', 'Bananas'])

print(df.loc[df.Apples==30 & True])      # It's OK
print(df.loc[True])                      # **doesn't work**
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the [`loc` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) *you* linked to:

> Allowed inputs are:
>
> - [...]
> - A boolean array of the **same length as the axis being sliced**, e.g. `[True, False, True]`.

If the mask is not of the same length, it assumes you are searching for a label in the column, and failing to find it, raises a `KeyError`.

---

Note that `df.Apples == 30 & True` has the same length as `df`.

```
df.Apples == 30 & True
```

Evaluates to

```
df.Apples == 0
```

Which is

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: Apples, dtype: bool
```

Because `==` has lower precedence than `&`. See [Operator Precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).